# How to insert multiple products slider in php

Tags: php, html

**The following section creates a product slider from the first 6 database elements. How can I insert the next database elements(from row 6 to row 12) in a new product slider?**

```
<section class="food" id="food">
    <div class="swiper product-slider">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <?php
                $sql = "SELECT* FROM products";
                $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $counter = 0;
                if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
                        ++$counter;
                        if($counter <= 6){
                            $id = $row['productId'];
                            $image = $row['productImg'];
                            $name = $row['productName'];
                            $price = $row['productPrice'];
                            $quantity = $row['productQuantity'];?>   
                            <form action="food.php" method="post" class="swiper-slide box">
                                <img src="<?php echo $image?>" alt="">
                                <h3><?php echo $name?></h3>
                                <div class="price"> $ <?php echo $price?></div>
                                <div class="stars">
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>
                                </div>
                                <a href="#" class="btn">add to cart</a>
                            </form><?php
                        }
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Carousel is configured to work on the class `product-slider` and not  on the `id="food"`, you can place an `if` in your `foreach` loop to start a new slider after 6 elements.

Something like

```
++$counter;
if($counter == 7){
?>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper product-slider">
         <div class="swiper-wrapper">
<?php
}
```

Furthermore, you need to change your breakpoint from 6 elements to 12. So you could just change your existing `if` from `<=6` to `<=12`. However, the best practice would be instead of limiting the PHP array to limit the original SQL query.

So edit your initial query to

```
SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 12
```

Here's the complete code

```
<section class="food" id="food">
    <div class="swiper product-slider">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 12";
                $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $counter = 0;
                if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
                        ++$counter;
                        if($counter == 7){
                        ?>
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="swiper product-slider">
                                 <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <?php
                        }

                        $id = $row['productId'];
                        $image = $row['productImg'];
                        $name = $row['productName'];
                        $price = $row['productPrice'];
                        $quantity = $row['productQuantity'];?>   
                        <form action="food.php" method="post" class="swiper-slide box">
                            <img src="<?php echo $image?>" alt="">
                            <h3><?php echo $name?></h3>
                            <div class="price"> $ <?php echo $price?></div>
                            <div class="stars">
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="btn">add to cart</a>
                        </form><?php
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: If instead the JS generating the carousel is hardcoded with the id `food`, please post your JS as well